# Strong induction $n=2^a\cdot b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Given $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists a non-negative integer $a$ and an odd integer $b$ such that $n=2^a\cdot b$

Base Case:
$n=1 =2^0\cdot1$

I.H: Assume its true for $n=1,2,\ldots,k$

How would i prove this?

Comment: Split into odd / even cases and use induction in the even case.

Comment: @BillDubuque what do u mean by latter case

Comment: If $\,n = 2m\,$ is even then by strong induction $\, m = 2^a b,\, b\, $ odd so $\,n = 2m = \,\ldots\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque i got same as him for even and for odd can i update my answer to see if im right

Comment: @BillDubuque i get the induction part but idk get why we need cases for even and odd

Comment: Pulling out a factor of $2$ is the most natural way to descend to a smaller instance. What other way do you propose?

Comment: i was just wondering how u came up with the cases

Comment: I added an answer explaining the key idea behind my hint.

Comment: See also my answer in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rather straight forward induction.

Base Case : $n=1$  is odd.

$n = 2 = 2^1 \times 1$, if you want another.

Now, let $1,...,k$ be covered in the hypothesis. Look at $k+1$.

Either $k+1$  is odd or even. If it is odd, then $k+1 = 2^0 (k+1)$, where $k+1$ is odd (of course). Hence, we are done in this case.

If  $k+1$ is even, then $\frac{k+1}{2} < k+1$ is an integer which has been covered in the inductive hypothesis, say $\frac{k+1}2 = 2^ab$, where $b$ is odd. Transposing, $k+1 = 2^{a+1}b$, where $b$ remains odd. Hence, $k+1$ can always be written in the desired form.

This completes the induction.

Comment: Thanks for spoiling the hint

Comment: @BillDubuque You are welcome. Having said that, I did not see your conversation above while I was typing this answer, so I will delete it... or maybe not.  The other answer is incorrect.

Comment: for even i got $2^{a+1}b$ but idk how to do odd

Comment: You don't  need to do the odd! If $n$ is odd,  then $n = 1\times n$ ,that's it! All you need is some power of two times an odd integer, right? So $1$ is a power of $2$, and $n$ is odd, and $n = 1\times n$! That's all, we have taken care of the odd case without needing the hypothesis at all.

Comment: @Yes, see my comments on the other answer. Perhaps you can be more persuasive than I.

Comment: @BillDubuque Oh, I see. I will join the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that this statament is reasonable: every number, odd or even could be written in this form.
When $n$ is odd $a$ must be $0$. When $n$ is even $a \ge1$.

So, more formally: take an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

- If $n$ is odd we can say that $n=2^0n$
- If $n$ is even consider the prime factorization of $n$, $n=2^{\alpha_1}*3^{\alpha_2}*...*p_n^{\alpha_n}$ note  that $ 2^{p_1}|n \space$ and $\space 2^{p_1+1} \not| n$ $\implies \exists b\in \mathbb{N}: n=2^{p_1}b$.

Comment: Use `\mid` ($a \mid b$) and `\not\mid` ($a \not\mid b$) rather than `|` ($a|b$) and `\not|` ($a \not| b$).

Comment: This is not a valid proof by induction. Moreover, you are essentially assuming what needs to be proved.

Comment: Why? I take a as the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization of n

Comment: This simple induction does not need strong results like prime factorization (and using them may be circular). In any case, I don't see any (strong) *induction* above, so it does not answer the question.

Comment: While one may argue that using the prime factorization theorem is circular, I think that it is just far too strong in the case above. First of all, a traditional proof of the prime factorization theorem, involves strong induction itself of a very similar form (if $n$ is prime, done, otherwise $n=ab$, where $1<a,b < n$ etc.) just replace the word prime by odd and $a$ by $2$, and apply the induction hypothesis, and we are done. Instead, going by the prime factor theorem is like proving a large theorem and taking a small corollary out of it. Like an ordinary couple living in a 100 bedroom house.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25930/242) for a proof along those lines, i.e. similar to the inductive proof that naturals $> 1$ can be written as a product of primes (i..e irreducibles). This question is a dupe of that one.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks, Honestly I write this because it was the first think that "translates" my intuition (i.e you can divide a number by 2 finitely many times). But surely is not an economic way to solve this problem

Comment: @Leonardo The point is that results like this are usually used to *motivate* more general results such as the (strong) inductive proof of *existence* of prime factorizations. By deriving it as a corollary of the more general result the proof is no longer a (strong) inductive proof, so it no longer serves as a good example for learning (strong) induction - which is usually the reason for posing such exercises.

Comment: @BillDubuque It's good we got it cleared up. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Indeed, thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you inquired how we could *discover* the proof that I hinted. The idea is simply that every natural $>0$ can be generated by repeatedly multiplying its odd part $\,\color{#c00}b\,$ by a power of $\,\color{#0a0}2.\,$ Said inductively: the set $\,S\,$ of naturals $> 0\,$ writable in form $\,\color{#0a0}2^a \color{#c00}b\,$ satisfies the following.

**Lemma** $ $ If $\,S\subseteq \Bbb N_{>0}$ contains all $\color{#c00}{\rm odds}$ and is closed under $\rm\color{#0a0}{multiplication\ by\ 2}\,$ then $\,S = \Bbb N_{>0}$

**Proof** $ $ Suppose for strong induction that $S$ contains every natural $< n.\,$ If $\,n\,$ is odd then $\,n\in S\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{hypothesis}$. Else $n = 2k\,$ for $k< n$ so $\,k\in S\,$ by induction, so $n = 2k\in S\,$ by $\rm\color{#0a0}{hypothesis}$.

**Remark** $ $ More generally, replacing $\,2\,$ by any natural $\,c > 1,\,$ and "odd" by nonmultiple of $\,c,\,$ the same proof  shows that any natural $>0\,$ can be written  in form $\,c^k b,\ c\nmid b\,$ (the above induction amounts to pulling out as many factors of $\,c\,$ as possible, i.e. until $\,c\nmid b).\,$ This representation is *unique*: $ $  if $\,c^kb = n = c^K d,\,$ wlog $\,K > k,\,$ then $\,b = c^{K-k}d\Rightarrow c\mid b \,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

**More generally** see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25930/242), which shows how this is a special case of *inductive generation of multiplicatively closed sets* (here uniqueness may fail).

**Beware** $ $ If $\,c\,$ is not prime then the cofactor $b$ need not be *coprime* to $\,c\,$ so powers of $\,c\,$ need not combine additively under multiplication, e.g. for $\,c = 6\,$ we have $\,(6^2\cdot 2)(6^3\cdot 3) = 6^6\,$ so we get an extra power of $\,6\,$ from $\,bb' = 2\cdot 3,\,$ which can't occur for prime $\,c=p\,$ by $\,p\nmid b,b'\Rightarrow p\nmid bb'$ by Euclid's Lemma.